# Can I use the perfect participle in a question? And can I use it after "instead of"?

Tags: questions, participles

> "Shouldn't the objects have disappeared instead of the writings on them having been changed?"

Is this sentence grammatically correct? If not then how can you make it grammatically correct? Can I use the perfect participle in a question? And can I use it after "instead of"? I've heard that the verbs that follow "instead of" should be verbs that end with "-ing". But what if the event after "instead of" happened in the past? What should you use?

Comment: The cited example is so syntactically weird that I wouldn't like to say for sure whether it's "syntactically" valid or not. For a relatively minor change that might feasibly count as an "improvement" (stylistically and/or syntactically), I'd at least ditch that cumbersome *second* instance of the Perfect verb form: *...instead of the writing on them **changing**.* In the real world, I imagine most native speakers wouldn't use the Perfect for the *first* clause either: *Shouldn't the objects **disappear**, instead of...* Rule of thumb - use Perfect when you ***must***, not when you ***can***.

Comment: @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica I used "Shouldn't the objects have disappeared" because if it's not a question, it is like saying "The objects should have disappeared", right?

Comment: ...in your case, I think ***instead of*** is a kind of "sentence adverb", which might be slightly tricky for nns to parse. Usually, the default "target" of ***instead*** is the immediately-preceding verb *(Shouldn't the objects have **disappeared**, instead of **getting bigger**?)* or noun *(Shouldn't the **objects** have disappeared, instead of **the magician's assistant**?).* But in your case it's the entire statement before ***instead*** that's being "contrasted".

Comment: ...in case you're not clear on this point, note that the question *Shouldn't the objects have disappeared?* is semantically ***exactly equivalent*** to the statement / assertion *The objects should have disappeared* in most contexts.

Comment: @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica Isn't saying "changing" in the second clause wrong because the event happened in the past?

Comment: @Flickspoo, the -ing in changing does not mean present tense, but continuous aspect, which can be in past continuous (was changing), present continuous (is changing) and future continuous (will be changing). Also, "changing" can act as an adjective, like "changing mood."

Comment: @Jan But what continuous tense should be used in the sentence I mentioned?

Comment: @Jan Are you saying that "changing" is an example of the continuous tenses?