# How is it correct to use the word "being" in "Shouldn't the items have disappeared instead of the writings on them being changed?"?

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction, questions

> "Shouldn't the items have disappeared instead of the writings on them being changed?

The event in the second part of the sentence happened in the past. How is it correct to use "being"?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I use the perfect participle in a question? And can I use it after "instead of"?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/239673/can-i-use-the-perfect-participle-in-a-question-and-can-i-use-it-after-instead)

Comment: ...as I pointed out before (when you asked about ***exactly*** the same example), that text is so "weird" it's not really a suitable case to deconstruct anyway.

Comment: What does answer my question?

Comment: @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica You told me in that thread (is the word "thread" right?) that "changing" is the right word. But there is some sort of outside force that made the writings change. So "being changed" is likely to be right. I'm just asking how it is right if the event happened in the past.

Comment: @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica I'll give another example and it might be clearer and easier for you to understand. "Shouldn't we have thrown the papers instead of drawing things on them?" How is "drawing" in this sentence right when the event happened in the past?

Comment: See several written instances of *He should have [gone to bed instead of staying](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22gone+to+bed+instead+of+staying%22) up late.* There are actually ***no*** written instances of the same with ***stayed*** instead of ***staying***. In fact, there are only 4 instances of that version on the entire Internet (compared to an estimated 1920 instances of my preferred version). I can't easily explain ***why*** my version is "correct" - all I know is what I as a native speaker would or wouldn't say myself.

Comment: (I *think* - but may be mistaken - that this is something to do with "parallel structures" at the *syntactic* level.)

Comment: @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica It is similar to the use of parallel structures but I haven't seen examples of it used in "instead of" sentences and they often just repeat words/make it similar.

Comment: Perhaps I found my answer in https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Participle, it's in the second usage of participles.

Comment: ***instead of*** (and ***rather than***) are very common contexts that strongly favour parallel constructions. Your link is really all about finding "names" for specific ways English "participles" can be used. But that's all within the framework of ***Latin-based*** syntax (which imho doesn't map very well to English anyway), and I don't see anything there about parallelism. I think your *specific* example is "off-puttingly non-parallel" partly because one half is "active verb" and the other "passive", ***and*** the "subject" of the first clause switches to "object" in the second.

Comment: @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica I thought you're saying my example has something to do with parallelism? Now you're saying it doesn't? And why does there need to be parellelism in the link I sent?

Comment: What I'm saying is that in constructions of the general form *[something] **instead of** [something else]*, we normally expect semantic ***and*** syntactic parallels between those two "somethings". But as explained in some detail now, that expected parallelism is weak to non-existent on both fronts in your example. Leading to an utterance which may or may not be "ungrammatical", but which I think most linguists would categorise as "unhappy".

Comment: @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica But you're the one that brought up parallelism.

Comment: @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica You said it's related to parallelism and now you're saying it's not. Did you just change your mind?

Comment: I haven't changed either what I'm saying or my mind. The stylistic principles involved here go way beyond even what most native Anglophones would understand, so it's no surprise if you have difficulty understanding what I'm trying to explain to you. Your example utterance ***unavoidably*** features parallelism (by the nature of the basic construction). But that parallelism is clumsily implemented, so ***it doesn't really work*** (because of sloppy / inconsistent juxtaposition of active/passive verbs and subject / object nouns).

Comment: ...but note that although my Literary Studies degree included Linguistics, that was 50 years ago, and so far as I recall we never went into details like this. So I might ask on ELU to see if someone there can explain more clearly exactly what principle of linguistic "happiness" is being "violated" by your utterance.

Comment: "linguistic 'happiness' "? What is that? Sorry, can you speak in layman's terms so that I can understand you easier? I'm not very good at English lol. 

So basically, you're saying that my example has parallelism but it doesn't work because of the sloppy juxtaposition of active/passive verbs and subject/object nouns? How are they a sloppy juxtaposition?

Comment: The fact that no-one else can be bothered to comment, answer, or vote on either this page OR the one you posted originally should be telling you something lol. In linguistic terms, an expression is "unhappy" if *native speakers don't like it* (particularly if they ***can't explain*** what's wrong with it, because it doesn't obviously break any syntactic rules). But I'm afraid to say that if you haven't grasped the point I've been trying to make by now, I don't think there's much point in me continuing to flog this particular dead horse.

Comment: Wdym "they can't explain what's wrong with it"? Are you saying something is wrong with my example? How so?

Comment: @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica Did you purposely not answer me? Or did you not see my comment? Answer me, pleeeaase.

Comment: This entire comment thread is essentially just me telling you that your example text is stylistically weak, and you repeatedly asking me "Why?". But either I'm unable to explain myself properly, or you're unable to understand what I'm saying. My point is we don't seem to be getting anywhere. Since it's more a matter of writing style than formal syntax, perhaps you could get some useful feedback by asking about that text on [Stack Exchange Writers](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions).